# ajax POST sending null

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, .net-core

I originally wrote the call as a GET but found a limitation with the length of the URI. Ideally, the call will take an object and turns it into a JSON format string, then sends it to a controller which will encrypt that string. The controller will send back a true/false if it succeeded.

My problem with POST, once it reaches the controller, the data parameter set from the ajax is null.

**Here is the ajax/js:**

```
var encActionURL = '@Url.Action("Encrypt", "Home")';
$.ajax({
    url: encActionURL,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    traditional: true,
    data: { jsonDoc: JSON.stringify(jsonDataFile) },
    success: /*OnSuccess*/ function (result) {
        // DO STUFF;
    }
});
```

**Here is the controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Encrypt(string jsonDoc)
{
    return serverConnection.Encrypt();
}
```

Note that, when I simply change the type to 'GET', it works great but when the form gets too long, it throws a 414 status error.

Most of the fixes found that I *seem* to have is the *'application/json'*. I've also set ajax to *traditional*.

Comment: "once it reaches the controller, a null value is sent instead." - do you mean the controller receives a null value, or the controller somehow returns null?  Are you sure you're hitting this controller with your post request?

Comment: instead of stringify have you thought about using the `JSON.parse` method also I do not think you need to set the `async:true nor the the traditional : true`

Comment: @WillardSolutions sorry, clarified in the post - the controller receives a null value. And it is hitting the controller when running since I put a breakpoint there.

Comment: Inspect the post request in the browser console - is data actually being posted?  If it is, trace it out server-side, if not, there's an issue somewhere in your JS.

Comment: How much data are you sending?  Are you trying to do file upload?

Comment: @WillardSolutions, Request Payload has the json I want to send if that means anything.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, it's basically a table of xy value pairs which can range from 1 to 100s of pairs, but I'm trying to encrypt those values in one call since they need to be associated with each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a rabbit-hole of security tokens and validating forms, it wasn't any of that... this might be a solution for anyone using ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC (5?) or just in general. Could have been a syntax mistake, return type mistake, or a combination.

**New Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    url: encActionURL,
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'jsonDoc': JSON.stringify(jsonDataFile) }, // NOTICE the single quotes on jsonDoc
    cache: false, 
    success: /*OnSuccess*/ function (result) {
        // DO STUFF;
    }
});
```

New Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EncryptJSON(string jsonDoc) // Switch to ActionResult, formerly JsonResult
    {
        return Json(serverConnection.Encrypt());
    }
```